# pass attributes through form.submit();

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work with single button upload file using javascript in a Django web app, and I've come to a point where I need to do 2 types of file upload and in order to do that I need the `name` attribute the submit button for the test, I need to know if there is an option to pass it through `onchange=this.form.submit();`

this works fine form me :

```html
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="replace">
        <button type="submit" name="replace">replace</button>
    </form>
    <form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="add">
        <button type="submit" name="add">add</button>
    </form>
```

what i am trying to do :

```html
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="file-upload-add" class="btn btn-primary">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span>Replace with CSV
            </label>
            <input id="file-upload-add" type="file" name="replace" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
        </form>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="file-upload-add" class="btn btn-primary">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span>add CSV
            </label>
            <input id="file-upload-add" type="file" name="add" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Create an eventhandler function for the onchange, and pass the name and the target to that function, and finally call the submit,

Comment: can you please link any tutorial to do that, I'm pretty noob in javascript!

Answer (score 1):

A submit button will only send its name/value pair if it is used to submit the form.

You are using JavaScript to submit the form instead so it won't be sent.

Put the name and value on an `<input type="hidden">` instead. You have seperate forms, so there is no need to distinguish which button was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can set same class name for every file input element

```
<input id="file-upload-add" class="file-input" type="file" name="replace" />

<input id="file-upload-add" class="file-input" type="file" name="add" />
```

then write a javascript like below to execute form submit when respective file input change is triggered

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("file-input");

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function () {
        inputs[i].parentElement.submit();
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that your HTML has to be in the same structure for this to work (i.e. same classname for every input file & form tag to be direct parent of input file element)

Comment: the problem is Django needs the name of the submit input in order to test which form is submitted on a page. I need to pass the submit button's name in Django view.